# Onclick on view pager in android does not work in my code

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

i have implemented view pager in my code and i have put on-click listener  on view pager but my on-click listener does not working i'll post my code

```
viewpager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.i("***","***");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "XXXX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **clicklistener** inside the item of **ViewPager**. This is not working because Child of ViewPager is intercepting event of parent(i.e ViewPager). E.G if you are adding ImageView inside ViewPager using PagerAdapter then use click of ImageView to make it simple

Comment: i have also used inside my adapter(instantiateItem()) but it is not working?

Comment: Show me what you have used?

Comment: is it possible to implement click listener in my activity as compare to my view pager adapter class?

Comment: you can implement in activity and can set same listener to Adapter class. Show me the code then i will show how it can be done

Answer (score 15):

I implemented custom `ViewPager`:

```
public class ClickableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setup();
    }

    public ClickableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new TapGestureListener());

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnViewPagerClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        mOnClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onViewPagerClick(ViewPager viewPager);
    }

    private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if(mOnClickListener != null) {
               mOnClickListener.onViewPagerClick(ClickableViewPager.this);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And example how to implement `onClickListener`:

```
ClickableViewPager viewPager = (ClickableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setOnViewPagerClickListener(new ClickableViewPager.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onViewPagerClick(ViewPager viewPager) {
                //yourCode
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is a way better answer. One listener for the entire viewPager, opposed to one for each view within it. This should be the accepted answer. Been searching hours to find this!

Comment: @Birrel does this implementation work for you? For me, OnTouchListener of ViewPager fires only when I perform scrolling, single tap is ignored.

Comment: @aleien, sorry but I cannot remember. I've been writing PHP almost exclusively since I used this solution, so it would take me some *getting up to speed* before I'd even be able to look at what I did and understand it. Just no time for that right now. Based on my comment, it looks like some or all of it worked out. Sorry I cannot be more useful.

Comment: @Gaket you didn't receive onSingleTapConfirmed event?

Comment: Nope. I put a debug break there, added a Log statement to be sure but didn't get the callback called.

Answer (score 0):

There is no onClick listener in ViewPager, You can use the same effect by using a Recyclerview instead of a ViewPager is shown as below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_scroll_page"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Using Recyclerview as horizontal then you can scroll it and get the click events. Please note that use the RecyclerView.Adapter