# ViewPager items in a ListView not clickable

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a ListView where each item contains a ViewPager (in a CardView, not sure if that matters). The desired behavior is that:

1. Clicks on the items work normally, as if the items were simple TextViews for example.
2. Swiping in the ViewPager works.

Right now, clicks on the ViewPager don't work. Clicking outside of the ViewPager does work as expected however, I had to set `focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"` for this to work. Other than that, there's nothing unusual in the code.

Comment: can you post some code please ?

Comment: try setting 'descendantFocusability' for the root of viewpager layout.

Comment: You mean clicking outside works after adding`focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"` ? is it ? then Why aren't you using `GestureDetector` instead ?

Comment: @AkshayBhat didn't have any effect.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna yes. I'm not sure how a GestureDetector would help in this case.

Comment: GestureDetector's `onSingleTapConfirmed` method is used to handle the click event, Try once.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna the touch ripple effect on the item would not work then...

Comment: @fhucho May be that will be the secondary issue, [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33123750/5067493) is good example of implementation, Try once, If Ripple effect didn't work then we will see that next..

Comment: Don't add the click listener to the view pager itself , set the listener at the root view of your viewpagers content.

Comment: @AndreClassen I have the click listener on the ViewPager's parent, I need the ripple effect to span the parent, not only the the ViewPager's content.